# Install R with shared library in OSX - liblzma library missing

Tags: r, macos, postgresql, lzma, plr

Operating system: OSX El Capitan 10.11.6 (15G1004)
R version: version 3.3.1
PostgreSQL 9.5.4 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76), 64-bit

I would like to install PL/R on my local PostgreSQL. 
From the installation page www.joeconway.com/plr/doc/plr-install.html, I opted for the second method and run `USE_PGXS=1 make` (I am not an expert, I am not sure what this line means), but I get this error:

> Package libR was not found in the pkg-config search path.
>   Perhaps you should add the directory containing 'libR.pc'
>   to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable.

As I understand from the installation notes at the link above, I need to install R with shared library. I couldn't find any specific instructions, only this [one](https://sagarnikam123.snipt.net/installing-r-with-shared-library-enable-r-shlib/). 
When I first run `sudo ./configure  --enable-R-shlib` I got an error saying that *gfortran* was missing and I added it with `brew install gcc`. Second time I run it, I got this error:

> checking lzma.h usability... no
>   checking lzma.h presence... no
>   checking for lzma.h... no
>   configure: error: liblzma library and headers are required.

Searching around, I thought I found a solution by installing the XZ package using the [XZ.pkg](https://sourceforge.net/projects/macpkg/files/XZ/) but it keeps giving me the same error.
I am not sure what I should do next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I had the same sort of difficulty (on the same OS version), I installed the xz package from the library cited in the CRAN page for Mac development tools:

http://R.research.att.com/libs/

Pick the version that matches your OS version (which is probably the most recent one in your case.)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. This is what I did:

1. Install brew.sh
2. brew install xz

That worked for me.